# HTML <dd> tag self-clone on browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul id="cjbox" class="cjbox">
    <li>
        <dl class="dl">
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_1.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_2.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_3.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_4.png"></dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dl class="dl">
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_1.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_2.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_3.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_4.png"></dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dl class="dl">
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_1.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_2.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_3.png"></dd>
            <dd><img src="/assets/images/gift/giftbox_4.png"></dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, my site self-cloned the `<dd>` tag in all `<li>` tag 4 times (please see image) and caused the website layout to break.

[dd tag self-clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Avr.png)

I checked my Javascript code, there is no code related to this HTML tag.

I have tried using different browsers like MS EDGE, Google Chrome, ... but this error still occurs.

How do I fix this error?

Your answer will be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean that your site "self-cloned"? Web pages don't magically clone random parts of themselves. Please provide more information

Comment: @j08691 As in the picture can be seen. My code is: Inside `<li>` is `<dl class="dl">`, inside it is 4 `<dd>` tag. However, when I opened it in the browser, the number of `<dd>` tags increased by itself to 16 for each `<dl class="dl">` which means 48 `<dd>` tags for 3 `<li>` but correct is 12 `<dd>` tag for 3 `<li>` tag.

Comment: @j08691 Due to the screen height restriction I only managed to capture 16 `<dd>` tags in the first `<li>` tag, other `<li>` tags also had the same problem.